# Which statistical model/method should I use?

Tags: sas

I have a data collected in New Jersey, and the units are individuals nested in four cities.
Within four cities, there are also three types of neighborhoods defined by someone.

I am trying to see if there is any difference in dep var (e.g., eating at a fast food restaurant more than once per week) across cities controlling for some individual level variables.

I am running a binary logit model controlling for the clustering at the city level. I used Proc Genmod in SAS.

My question is, does it make sense if I include dummy variables for cities while I am controlling for the clustering at the city level?

```
proc genmod data=njcob.foranalysis;
    class cityid; /* <= ID for four cities*/
    model ffwk1ormore=
    city1 city2 /* <= not sure about this part */
    male age6and11 age12and19 black hispanic fgnborn highsch more_highsch povlevel / dist=bin; 
    repeated subject=cityid / type=ind; 
run;
```

Or is there a better model?
I would appreciate any advice! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well, you want to do a model by city. (In this case you assume there is a difference of comportment between each city)

If you add the dummy variable city, it will be constant for each model, so it is not a best practice to keep them.

If you want to know if there is a effect "city", you could make one model with the city in the model as dependent variable (as a factor or as dummy variable) and check if the parameter is significant or not.

Comment: I am running the model with all cities together and trying to see if there is any difference between them controlling for individual and neighborhood characteristics. And I am adjusting for the clustering effect at the neighborhood level in the model. Does it make sense?

Comment: ok, I think it make sense to add them as dummy variable. But they should probably be highly correlated with the other variables which are described at the neighborhood level(especially if they are continuous variables. Maybe a stepwise or lasso selection of variables could confirm you if you have to keep them or not.